# View All Binds, wxpython

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

Is there a way to view all binds of an object?

```
x=wx.Button(self,-1,"hi")
x.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,self.Press)


###
print x.ShowAllBindingData()  #Function doenst exists
[['EVT_BUTTON','Press']]
```

Is there anything like that

Comment: wxWindows inherit from wxEventHandler so this page my help http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.8/wx_wxevthandler.html#wxevthandlergetclientdata

Comment: May not be possible: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/wxpython-users/zjjXGGQxSDo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible. Mind you, if it were possible, it wouldn't be very useful because even if you don't call `Bind()` on the object itself, you could still process the event in different ways, e.g. by handling it at parent window level (for command events and the like only) or by pushing a custom event handler on top of the object or (this is probably C++-only though) overriding the virtual `ProcessEvent()` method directly.